# How to use hostname variable in a dictionary object?

Tags: ansible

I'm setting up an Ansible playbook to create a Let's Encrypt certificate with DNS challenge. The first step in this process is to use the `community.crypto.acme_certificate` module to get the value of the DNS challenge. That value is returned in a dictionary object, which I can then put into a TXT record in DNS to download the certificate from Let's Encrypt.

The value of the challenge is returned in this dictionary key, which contains the FQDN of the host::

`{{ dns_challenge['challenge_data_dns']['_acme-challenge.<FQDN of the host>'] }}`

If I know the hostname, I can retrieve the challenge value. But the problem is that this playbook will be   run on numerous hosts, so it needs to make use of a hostname variable.

But I can't figure out what to put in place of `<FQDN of the host>`. `{{ inventory_hostname }}` doesn't work because I can't nest variables. `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` doesn't work and gives the error `dict object' has no attribute 'hostvars[inventory_hostname]`.

Is there a way to insert the hostname variable into this dictionary object? Or is there a completely different approach I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: Since the dictionary object is already contained in double curly brackets, it recognizes `inventory_hostname` without the second set of brackets, or without needing `hostvars`. So
`{{ dns_challenge['challenge_data_dns'][inventory_hostname] }}` works.